# BigQuery + nested for

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using *Gmail logs for BigQuery* for data analysis. I need to know if a email has been replied; for that (using python):

- I get *received* email list from BQ specific query
- I get *sent* email list from BQ specific query

And then, in python, I use a nested `for` searching if an email in received list exist (with "Re:" in subject) in sent list.

This is actually working, but nested `for` is not a great scalable solution, specially if you have thousand of emails in both lists.

Any idea if all this can be done entirely in BigQuery? 
(or maybe reduce nested loop impact)

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please share your query and table schema?

Comment: @LeiChen this is part of my code (with query example and nested for) http://pastebin.com/rf9uyQCW and also the schema (is google's official schema for gmail logs): http://support.google.com/a/answer/7230050?hl=en&ref_topic=723331